# How to convert List<string> to List<object> specific property in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How to convert `List<string>` to `List<object>` property in c#

We have a list of email id's

```
List<string> str= new List<string>{"abc1@gmail.com","abc2@gmail.com"};
```

and now we have to assign these email IDs to the list of an employee `List<Employee>` emailId property.

```
var emplist = new List<Employee>() ;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-7.0).

```
var emplist = str.Select(x => new Employee { EmailId = x }).ToList();
```

---

`Select()` is used for projecting each element of a sequence(*in your case it is string email id*) into a new sequence i.e. the `Employee` object.

Answer (score 0):

**We can convert or assign `List<string>` to `List<object>` to specific property**

```
//here Employee is an Object type
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>() { "abc1@gmail.com", "abc2@gmail.com" }  ;
            var emplist= new List<Employee>() ;
            if(list.Any())
                list.ForEach(str => emplist.Add(new Employee { EmailId = str }));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public class Employee {
            public string EmailId { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Why `if(list.Any())`? Isn't that redundant?

Comment: we have used ```if(list.Any())``` because,  suppose if your List<string> if null or if count 0, it wont throw the exception

Comment: If it's `null`, `.Any` throws an ArgumentNullException, so you're just trading a NullReferenceException calling `ForEach` on a null `list` for an ArgumentNullException calling `.Any`: https://rextester.com/VPH56176

Comment: If it's empty (count == 0), no exception is thrown: https://rextester.com/GTDZN35007

Comment: @Samadhan, If you look at my solution, it is elegant. We do not need to consider any edge case here. If you want to check null then only you have to add a condition like `if(str == null)`.